# How to check for No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header error

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

When using XMLHttpRequest in JavaScript, is it possible to distinguish between the following two errors (GET completely failed / No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header)?

[image: error log]

Obviously, readyState and status of the XMLHttpRequest object don't differ. I tried to use window.onerror to catch all errors but apparently, these two errors do not trigger the callback function.

Comment: You probably have to use the serverside to check for that header. Create a small serverside script, and just call that with ajax

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin adds a header to the response that instructs the client not to allow calls in- or outside of the originating domain (depending on the way it is configured). The call to retrieve data from a blocked domain will not even leave the client.

Answer (score 0):

Your best course of action would be to prevent this error from even occurring in the first place. By making sure the server adds the domain you're trying to access from your script to the Access-Control-Allow-Origin setting you don't have to deal with it client-side.

That said, you should be able to attach a handler to the error event of the XMLHttpRequest object. Using the error message you might be able determine what went wrong; but that is of lesser interest. It doesn't matter to the client what went wrong, only that it isn't going to get it's data, so you can plan accordingly.

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

oReq.addEventListener("error", transferFailed);

oReq.open();

function transferFailed(evt) {
  console.log("An error occurred while transferring the file.");
}
```

More information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Asynchronous_request